# passing function argument to axios call

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm playing around with this API https://covid19.mathdro.id/api what I want to do is get a value based on the arg set in the function. for example.

```
const fetchCases = arg => {
  axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api").then(response => console.log(response.data.arg))
}

fetchCases("confirmed")
```

unfortunately, this yields undefined. How do you guys go about passing args such as this on fetch calls? what would be the best approach for these types of calls?

Comment: Your URL should be a string. How are you wanting to incorporate `arg` into the request?

Comment: typo, you are correct the URL is a string. I want to be able to pass either confirmed, recovered and deaths as an arg and get their associated object based on the arg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access the response.data object like

```
response.data[arg]
```

For your example

```
const fetchCases = arg => {
  axios.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api').then(response => console.log(response.data[arg))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the API you put in the question, it return data from the route *https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed*, in this case, you can do something like this:

```js
const fetchCases = argument => {
  axios.get(`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/${argument}`).then(response => console.log(response))
}

fetchCases("confirmed")
```

To get the endpoint to get the confirmed cases

```js
const fetchCases = argument => {
  axios.get(`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api`).then(response => console.log(response[argument]))
// Above you need to use bracket notation because argument is a function parameter
}
```

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, you should use `${encodeURIComponent(argument)}`

Comment: correct, but if you want a global total you can do so by getting ```response.data.confirmed``` and that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I edit the response to made what you say, but the response is the endpoint to made the GET call to the and obtain the data you need